# Zip and even function on prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm new at Prolog. I have managed to do the `zip/3` predicate for the question below. Can anybody help me with the `pair/1` predicate? Thank you.

`zip(L1, L2, L)`: The list L is formed by “zipping” the first 2 arguments.
The result should be like this:

```
?- zip([a, b, c], [x, y, z], L).
L = [a, x, b, y, c, z]
?- zip([a, b], [x, y, z], L).
false
?- zip([a, b, c, d], X, [a, p, b, q, c, r, d, s]).
X = [p, q, r, s]
```

The solution:

```
zip([], [], []).
zip([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [X,Y|Zs]) :- 
   zip(Xs,Ys,Zs).
```

`pair(L)`: All elements in L occurs exactly twice. The result:

```
?- pair([a, b, b, c, a, c]).
true
?- pair([a, a, b, b, a, a]).
false
?- pair([a, a, b, c, d, d, c, X]).
X = b
```

Comment: I can see no mistake. Can zou point out zour problem again?

Comment: @User im stuck at the second part. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first pass of logic would say:

- The list `[X,X]` is a list whose elements only appear twice
- The list `[H|T]` is a list whose elements only appear twice if we remove `H` from `T` (yielding `T1`), and `H` is not contained in `T1`, and `T1` is a list whose elements only appear twice.

That would lead to:

```
twice([H|T]) :-
    select(H, T, T1),    % T1 is T with one occurrence of H removed
    \+ member(H, T1),
    twice(T1).
twice([X,X]).
```

This works great for:

```
?- twice([a, b, b, c, a, c]).
true ;
false.

?- twice([a, a, b, b, a, a]).
false.
```

But:

```
?- twice([a, a, b, c, d, d, c, X]).
false.
```

The reason for this is that `member(X, T)` will succeed if it can find an instantiation of variables in `X` and `T` which make it true. If `T` has a variable and `X` is an atom, then `member(X, T)` can be made true by unifying the variable in `T` with `X`.

So we need a "modified" `member` predicate (we'll call `is_in`) which behaves the way we want:

```
twice([H|T]) :-
    select(H, T, T1),    % T1 is T with one occurrence of H removed
    \+ is_in(H, T1),
    twice(T1).
twice([X,X]).

is_in(X, [H|_]) :-       % X is in [H|_] if...
    X == H.              % X and H are the same ("member" would use '=' here)
is_in(X, [_|T]) :-       % X is in [_|T] if...
    is_in(X, T).         % X is in T
```

Then we get:

```
?- twice([a, b, b, c, a, c]).
true ;
false.

?- twice([a, a, b, b, a, a]).
false.

?- twice([a, a, b, c, d, d, c, X]).
X = b ;
false.
```

The key here is `==` which checks if terms are already equal *without* attempting to instantiate any of the variables. If you have `b == X` it will fail, which is what we want. However, if we had `b = X`, it would succeed because Prolog would instantiate `X` to `b` to make it successful.

The other key is that `select/3` *will* instantiate variables to succeed, which is necessary in order to instantiate `X` in the example above.

The one limitation of the above implementation is that the most general query `twice(L)`, where `L` is variable, will fail:

```
?- twice(L).
% Hmm.... I'm waiting....
```

This can be resolved by controlling the length of the list in the `twice/1` predicate:

```
twice([H|T]) :-
    length([H|T], _),   % We don't actually use the length value, so _
    select(H, T, T1),    % T1 is T with one occurrence of H removed
    \+ is_in(H, T1),
    twice(T1).
twice([X,X]).
```

Then we also get:

```
?- twice(L).
L = [_G8, _G8, _G14, _G14] ;
L = [_G8, _G11, _G8, _G11] ;
L = [_G8, _G11, _G11, _G8] ;
L = [_G8, _G8, _G14, _G14, _G20, _G20] ;
L = [_G8, _G8, _G14, _G17, _G14, _G17] ;
...
```

Or:

```
?- twice([a,b|T]).
T = [a, b] ;
T = [b, a] ;
T = [a, b, _G306, _G306] ;
T = [a, _G303, b, _G303] ;
T = [a, _G303, _G303, b] ;
T = [b, a, _G306, _G306] ;
```

Finally, with the above definition, `twice([]).` fails. If you want to define `[]` as succeeding, you would just replace `twice([X,X]).` with `twice([]).`.